# When using the same React component multiple times, is it more performant to assign it to a variable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

```
<div>
  <SomeComponentWithProps propA={'some prop'} propB={'some other prop'} >
  <SomeComponentWithProps propA={'some prop'} propB={'some other prop'} >
</div>
```

Is there a performance benefit to refactoring the above code to:

```
const someComponent = <SomeComponentWithProps propA={'some prop'} propB={'some other prop'} >
<div>
   {someComponent}
   {someComponent}
</div>
```

Would the assigned component be rendered and cached?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a performance benefit to refactoring the above code to:

In theory yes, since you are calling `React.createElement` only once. But whether it makes a noticeable difference in your application is another question. Most likely not.

> Would the assigned component be rendered and cached?

**tl;dr:** No.

`React.createElement` basically returns a component "descriptor". The component is not instantiated or rendered at that point. We can easily test this (note that there is no console output from the constructor):

```js
class Foo extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    console.log('inside constructor');
  }
 
  render() {
    return 'Foo';
  }
}

const component = <Foo />;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Lets look at the component descriptor:

```js
function Foo({bar}) {
  return <span>{bar}</span>;
}

console.log(<Foo bar={42} />);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

You can see, all the `React.createElement` returns is an object that holds information about which function to call, the props to pass and some meta data information.

The actual rendering happens later.